# Call default interface method which is overridden in superclass

Tags: java, interface, java-8, default-method

I have a interface and abstract class.

```
public class TEST extends Abstract implements Inter2{
    void print() {
        toDO();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TEST().toDO();
    }
}

abstract class Abstract {

    public void toDO() {
        System.out.println("Abstract is called");
    }
}

interface Inter2 {

    default void toDO() {
        System.out.println("Inter2 is called");
    }
}
```

I want to force class interface default methods instead of abstract class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32478021/2775450

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to override toDO in the TEST class:

```
@Override
public void toDO() {
    Inter2.super.toDO();
}
```

Comment: Java is quite logical here - for you can implement multiple interfaces, that is why you have to prefix super. If super is alone, then it refers to the only one superclass that can be extended.