# In multiple inheritance between abstract class and interface

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, default, multiple-inheritance

In case of multiple inheritance with abstract class and interface. Abstract class dance() is called.why is the priority given to abstract class method but not default method in interface.

```
public class Child extends Absclass implements Interfc{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Child c = new Child();
    c.dance();
    }
}
Abstract class Absclass{
    public void dance(){
    System.out.println("abstract dancing");
    }
}
Interface Interfc{
    default public void dance(){
    System.out.println("interface dancing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just the rules of the language? You've provided an implementation of `dance()`, so there's no need to invoke the default method. What would be the benefit of the alternative approach?

Comment: See the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471220/super-class-method-and-interface-default-method-conflict-resolution for why this is the case. It's basically a defined rule in JLS.